# How hard is composing a song like ancient Greek music today?

Tags: composition, instruments

And by this question I mean a song that *sounds* like an actual ancient Greek song, with ancient Greek instruments (lyre, kithara, salpinx, etc.) being used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's effectively impossible, because we only know indirectly what their music might have sounded like, and there are almost no surviving working instruments.

We know quite a lot about the music theory the Greeks developed — there are a number of excellent posts on this site in that regard — but the actual sound of the music is, in essence, guesswork — though guesswork backed up a some outstanding and detailed research.

Comment: Has anyone tried to make those instruments, which could emulate the sounds?

Comment: @Tim yes, though the accuracy is debated, and still doesn’t inform the overall sound of the music, such as rhythm.

Comment: @Tim making the instruments is the easy part.  Consider the similarity between e.g. the [oud](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oud) and the [lute](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lute) and the differences between traditional North African music and the music of Renaissance Europe.  Or compare the many widely disparate styles of music one can play on a keyboard tuned in 12-tone equal temperament (and the even greater variety one can achieve by varying the tuning).

Comment: Sting's *When We Dance* is in [Lydian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lydian_mode). Sounds wack. Unlike REM's *Man On the Moon*, presumably because he can "actually maintain a harmony rigorously fixed on" the mode.

Comment: @Mazura The modern Lydian mode has nothing to do with the ancient Greek musical system except for millenia-later music theorists choosing a Greek name.